Падает gdb при создании потока
Пытаюсь отладить многопоточную программу в QtCreator с помощью gdb, но она падает при любом создании потока(пытался просто в мейне запустить тривиальный поток со слипом, но он так тоже падает)
Падает именно отладчик, программа прекрасно запускается и работает, но при переходе отладчика через функцию создания потока вылетает SIGSTOP в stacktrace видео, что последнее, что пыталась выполнить программа были pthread_create.c и clone.s
Кто-нибудь знает с чем это может быть связано и как это решить?
